# Search Arabic word with accent marks/diacritics

Tags: regex, flutter, dart, arabic

I have a [JSON file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGN5L.png) which contains Arabic words with accent marks /diacritics,

I'm trying to search with normal Arabic words without marks then highlight the searched word with an accent

> EX: User search with 'صلوات' without any accent will return
> "صَّلَوَاتِ" so I can highlight it
>
> عَلَى أَنْ تَعْبُدُوا اللَّهَ وَلَا تُشْرِكُوا بِهِ شَيْئًا،
> وَالصَّلَوَاتِ الْخَمْسِ، وَأَسَرَّ كَلِمَةً خَفِيَّةً أَنْ لَا
> تَسْأَلُوا النَّاسَ شَيْئًا
>
> will get
>
> عَلَى أَنْ تَعْبُدُوا اللَّهَ وَلَا تُشْرِكُوا بِهِ شَيْئًا،
> وَال**صَّلَوَاتِ** الْخَمْسِ، وَأَسَرَّ كَلِمَةً خَفِيَّةً أَنْ لَا
> تَسْأَلُوا النَّاسَ شَيْئًا

---

*Search Method used on textformfield*

```
List<Hades> hadesList = [];            \\json file list 
List<Hades> searchHadesList = [];      

Future<void> searchHadesText(String text) {
    searchHadesList = hadesList
        .where((element) => RemoveExtinctionsAtWord()
            .normalise(element.hades)
            .contains(RemoveExtinctionsAtWord().normalise(text)))
        .toList();
  }
```

in this code, I have to remove both diacritics from the searched text and the JSON file in order to compare between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add optional diacritic mark pattern after each char:

```dart
var output = text.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(word.split("").join("\\p{M}*"), caseSensitive: false, unicode: true), (Match m) => "<span>${m[0]}</span>")
```

Notes:

- `\p{M}` - matches any diacritic mark
- `unicode: true` enables the use of Unicode property classes like `\p{M}` in the pattern
- `.replaceAllMapped` is required since the match value should be used in the replacement